# why the result is "2" of unsigned int (1) - unsigned int (0xFFFFFFFF)

Tags: c

Please look at the following codes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 1;
    unsigned int b = -1;

    printf("0x%X\n", (a-b));

    return 0;
}
```

The result is 0x2.

I　think the integer promotion should not happen because the type of both of "a" and "b" are unsigned int. But the result beats me.... I don't know the reason.

By the way, I know the arithmetic result should be 2 because 1-(-1)=2. But the type of b is unsigned int. When assign the (-1) to b, the value of b is 0xFFFFFFFF actually. It is the maximum value of unsigned int. When one small unsigned value subtract one big value, the result is not that I expect.

From the answer below, I think maybe the overflow is a good explanation。
Now I writes other test codes. It proves the overflow answer is right.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int c = 1;
    unsigned int d = -1;


    printf("0x%llx\n", (unsigned long long)c-(unsigned long long)d);

    return 0;
}
```

The result is "0xffffffff00000002". It is I expect.

Comment: thanks, but i know the arithmetic result.

Answer (score 8):

```
unsigned int a = 1;
```

This initializes `a` to 1.  Actually, since `1` is of type `int`, there's an implicit `int`-to-`unsigned` conversion, but it's a trivial conversion that doesn't change the value or representation).

```
unsigned int b = -1;
```

This is more interesting.  `-1` is of type `int`, and the initialization implicitly converts it from `int` to `unsigned int`.  Since the mathematical value `-1` cannot be represented as an `unsigned int`, the conversion is non-trivial.  The rule in this case is (quoting section 6.3.1.3 of the C standard):

> the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more
>   than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until
>   the value is in the range of the new type.

Of course it doesn't actually have to do it that way, as long as the result is the same.  Adding `UINT_MAX+1` ("*one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type*") to -1 yields `UINT_MAX`.  (That addition is defined mathematically; it's not itself subject to any type conversions.)

In fact, assigning `-1` to an object of any unsigned type is a good way to get the maximum value of that type without having to refer to the `*_MAX` macros defined in `<limits.h>`.

So, assuming a typical 32-bit system, we have `a == 1` and `b == 0xFFFFFFFF`.

```
printf("0x%X\n", (a-b));
```

The *mathematical* result of the subtraction is `-0xFFFFFFFE`, but that's obviously outside the range of `unsigned int`.  The rules for unsigned arithmetic are similar to the rules for unsigned conversion; the result is 2.

Comment: Actually i know b is 0xFFFFFFFF actually because of unsigned. Can i understand this result because of overflow of unsigned int?

Comment: @linuxer: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Strictly speaking, unsigned types don't overflow or underflow, but that's just a quibble about what the words mean.  You can think of `1 - 0xFFFFFFFF` as underflowing, yielding a mathematical result that's outside the range of `unsigned int`, which is then adjusted back into the range, yielding 2.  Mathematically, the result is reduced modulo `UINT_MAX+1`.

Comment: I think if I could use the unsigned long long to avoid this issue. For example, I change the codes to "printf("0x%llX\n", (unsigned long long)(a-b));". But the result still is 0x2.

Comment: @linuxer: It's the same for any unsigned type (except that `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` might promote to `signed int` in some contexts).  `unsigned long long` arithmetic wraps modulo `ULLONG_MAX+1`.

Comment: because unsigned char and unsigned short could be promote to signed int. And the value of (a-b) is out of range of unsigned long. So I want to let it promote to unsigned long long. It should represent the ULONG_MAX+1

Comment: I wrote other test codes, and updated my post. It proves your answer is right. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Who says you're suffering integer promotion? Let's pretend that your integers are two's complement (likely, though not mandated by the standard) and they're only four bits wide (not possible according to the standard, I'm just using this to simplify things).

```
int   unsigned-int  bit-pattern
---   ------------  -----------
  1              1         0001
 -1             15         1111
                         ------
  (subtract with borrow) 1 0010
   (only have four bits)   0010  -> 2
```

You can see here that you can get the result you see without any promotion to signed or wider types.

Comment: how about changing the codes like "printf("0x%llX\n", (unsigned long long)(a-b));", But the result still is 0x2.

Comment: @linuxer, that will calculate `a-b` using unsigned int and _then_ cast the result to a wider type. That's why there's no difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you subtract a negative number, it is the equivalent of adding a positive number.

```
a = 1
b = -1

(a-b) = ?
((1)-(-1)) = ?
(1-(-1)) = ?
(1+1) = ?
2 = ?
```

At first you might think that this isn't allowed, since you specified an `unsigned int`; however, you are also converting `signed int` (the -1 constant) to an `unsigned int`.  So, you are effectively storing the exact same bits into the unsigned int (0xFFFF).

Then, in the expression, you take the negative of the 0xFFFF value, which of course **forces** the number to be signed.  In effect, you are circumventing the `unsigned` directive at ever step.

Comment: This isn't what is happening here.  Both are positive numbers before the subtraction occurs.

Comment: Subtraction in computers is done with complements, so the complement of 0xFFFF is (on your hardware) 1.  See the edit, and you'll see how you are storing in an unsigned int but forcing it back to signed at every step.

Comment: Nope.  The conversions and arithmetic are defined in terms of *values*, not representations.  On a system that doesn't use 2's-complement, the conversion of `-1` from `int` to `unsigned int` still yields `UINT_MAX`, but it changes the bits.  In the expression `a-b`, both operands are unsigned; there are no negative values involved.

Comment: I am agree with you, Keith. So I am confusing by the result. Because i don't think there is any negative value involved.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a compiler warning that you probably ignored or turned off, but it's still possible to store -1 in an unsigned integer. Internally, -1 is stored on a 32-bit machine as 0xffffffff. So if you subtract 0xffffffff from 1, you end up with -0xfffffffe, which is 2. (There are no negative numbers, a negative number is the maximum integer value plus one minus the number).

Bottom line - signed or unsigned doesn't matter at all, it only comes to play when you compare values.

And mathematically speaking, 1 - (-1) = 1+1.

Comment: Why should there be a warning?  The value `-1` is converted from `int` to `unsigned int`, and the result is well defined.

Comment: Because of this: `warning 68: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign`

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Compilers can warn about anything they like.

Comment: MSVC is similar: `warning C4245: 'initializing' : conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch`. It's just a common cause of subtle bugs, so most compilers warn about it. Typically only at warning level "nitpick", but that's my preferred level.